# How do I build ASP.NET web site to send push notification to windows store app

Tags: windows, push-notification, windows-8.1

I want to send Push notification to my apps, on both Windows 8.1 and Windows phone 8.1 from an ASP.NET web application as an alternative to Microsoft Azure Mobile Service.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

For sending Push notifications to your devices from your website, use Windows Push Notification Services (**WNS**). Sending Push notification directly to devices is not possible, you need WNS for the communication.

Read this article for the details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh913756.aspx

**Sending a notification**

**Note**  This is just an example, not cut-and-paste code that you can successfully use in your own code.

```
 POST https://cloud.notify.windows.com/?token=AQE%bU%2fSjZOCvRjjpILow%3d%3d HTTP/1.1
 Content-Type: text/xml
 X-WNS-Type: wns/tile
 Authorization: Bearer EgAcAQMAAAAALYAAY/c+Huwi3Fv4Ck10UrKNmtxRO6Njk2MgA=
 Host: cloud.notify.windows.com
 Content-Length: 24

 body....
```

Comment: Thank you, Please where can I get a walkthrough of how to write the code for the ASP.NET website that will serve as the cloud service and will send for instance a push toast to the app through the WNS, the authentication and all stuffs. If you have a link to a complete example I would be glad as I just started programming not long